# Can't add sqlite.interpop.dll

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm would use SQLite. I added reference System.Data.SQLite.dll ("copy local". Got it from system.data.sqlite.org x64 or x86) but when it compile get error: Can't load DLL "SQLite.Interpop.dll"
I would add reference SQLite.Interpop.dll but it says "it is not a library or com". Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in diffirent versions of .dll